# Unexpected end of block data in Gradle sync

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to start a project in Android Studio v0.5.4, but I keep getting the following error:

```
[ 130340]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: unexpected end of block data 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: unexpected end of block data
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:206)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:467)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:546)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

Possibly related is that I get this error when I try to access my build.gradle:

```
InvalidVirtualFileAccessException: Accessing invalid virtual file: jar:///home/alex/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/gradle/0.9.1/15633e70af52912588608f2675c85c4e11813c7/gradle-0.9.1-sources.jar!/com; original:27647; found:-: Accessing invalid virtual file: jar:///home/alex/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.tools.build/gradle/0.9.1/15633e70af52912588608f2675c85c4e11813c7/gradle-0.9.1-sources.jar!/com; original:27647; found:-
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Other information:

Using gradle 1.10, and gradle-wrapper.properties confirms this.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `/home/alex/.gradle/caches/` folder?

Comment: Just tried that, and still ended up with the same error. I've also tried deleting my .gradle directory before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

buildToolsVersion was set to 19 and I had 19.0.3 installed. I solved it by changing this line:

```
buildToolsVersion = "19"
```

to

```
buildToolsVersion = "19.0.3"
```

in build.gradle.